# How do I switch between views like home screen

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

How do I switch between multiple `UIView`'s using one `UIViewController` just like the iPhone home screen. If you need clarification please ask, don't thumbs down please.

Comment: The home screen is just a scroll view with page control. Daniel's answer will do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a UIScrollView...[this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/) sample code from apple does what you want to do