# Switch between scrolling views with swipe?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

What would be the best way to set up a group of views where each view acts as a scrolling view (can be scrolled up and down). And you can switch between these views with a swipe to the left or right?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a UIScrollView that has all of your objects in it.
If you need more help just see these:

- [How to use UIScrollView to switch between UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943393/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-switch-between-uiviews)
- [How to use UIScrollView to switch between UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943393/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-switch-between-uiviews)
- [How do I switch between views like home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940180/how-do-i-switch-between-views-like-home-screen)